# Saxon-EE truncating content in validation errors

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, saxon

I am using the .NET "port" of Saxon-EE 9.7.0.7 to validate XML documents in a C# Windows service. When the content of an element does not match the type defined for the element in the schema, the element's actual content can be truncated. For example, when using this code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Test.xml");
Processor proc = new Processor(true);
SchemaValidator validator;
StringBuilder validationErrors;
string result;

proc.SetProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/validation-warnings", "true");
proc.SchemaManager.XsdVersion = "1.0";
proc.SchemaManager.Compile(new Uri(@"C:\Test.xsd"));

validator = proc.SchemaManager.NewSchemaValidator();
validator.SetSource(doc.CreateReader());
validator.ErrorList = new ArrayList();

validator.Run();

validationErrors = new StringBuilder();

foreach (StaticError e in validator.ErrorList)
    validationErrors.AppendLine(e.ToString());

result = validationErrors.ToString();
```

to validate this document:

```
<root>
  <child>The content of this element is not valid.</child>
</root>
```

against this schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="child">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{0,3}" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Saxon-EE returns this error message:

> The content "**The content of this element is...**" of element  does not match the required simple type. Value "**The content of this element is...**" contravenes the pattern facet "[0-9]{0,3}" of the type of element child

On the other hand, Xerces 2.11, validating the same document against the same schema, returns:

> cvc-pattern-valid: Value '**The content of this element is not valid.**' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[0-9]{0,3}' for type '#AnonType_childroot'.

and .NET's built-in schema validation returns:

> The 'child' element is invalid - The value '**The content of this element is not valid.**' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Pattern constraint failed.

Is there a way to configure Saxon-EE *not* to truncate the invalid content when reporting the error? Saxon has worked very well for us in terms of validating (both XSD 1.0 and 1.1) and transforming (XSLT 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0) XML ever since we licensed it, but this is becoming a significant issue. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How would you have the diagnostic message read if the string value were 1k long?  1M?

Comment: @kjhughes, Xerces returns the entire content (even 1MB). .NET returns the first 1KB, so *technically*, it is truncating, but that would be acceptable to me since none of my content will approach that length.

Comment: Perhaps you could subclass [**net.sf.saxon.lib.StandardErrorListener**](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/StandardErrorListener.html) and set `errorListener` in the [**Saxon configuration file**](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/configuration/configuration-file/) to use your custom error listener that constructs diagnostic messages that meet your specific requirements regarding string value truncation.

Comment: That's worth a try. I'll give it a shot and let you know if that will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know *WHY* you think the truncation is a "significant issue": how are you using the error information?

The error messages are intended primarily for human consumption, and the main purpose of including a fragment of the source document content is to enable easy recognition of where the error occurs. I don't think many users would be pleased if we output the entire content of a 10Kb text node, and it's obviously a matter of judgment where to draw the line.

If you want to customize the reporting, or to automate the analysis of the validation errors, you can either write your own `ErrorListener` as suggested by @kjhughes, or an `InvalidityHandler` which makes the information more easily accessible, or you can work from the XML validation report. For this example the validation report is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-report xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/validation"
                   system-id="file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xml">
   <error line="2"
          column="12"
          path="/Q{}root[1]/Q{}child[1]"
          xsd-part="2"
          constraint="cvc-datatype-valid.1">The content "The content of this element is..." of element &lt;child&gt; does not match the required simple type. Value "The content of this element is..." contravenes the pattern facet "[0-9]{0,3}" of the type of element child</error>
   <meta-data>
      <validator name="SAXON-EE" version="9.8.0.9"/>
      <results errors="1" warnings="0"/>
      <schema file="test.xsd" xsd-version="1.1"/>
      <run at="2018-02-28T12:47:28.527Z"/>
   </meta-data>
</validation-report>
```

and because this includes a full path to the invalid element, you can easily expand it (using XSLT 3.0 and xsl:evaluate) to contain the complete content of the node if that's what you want.

If you run validation from the command line, you can get this report using the option -report:report.xml. From the s9api `SchemaValidator` you can get it using `validator.setValidityReporting()`.

Comment: I agree with what you say about it being only useful for human consumption and that it's a matter of judgment where to draw the line. That's why I was hoping it was something configurable. It's only a "significant issue" for us -- I'm not saying it's significant for anyone else. It is for our specific circumstances because the first part of several of our content values are the same, and when truncated, the human consuming the validation error doesn't necessarily know which one. I'll give the suggestions you and @kjhughes have made a try and let you know which one worked best for us. Thanks!